# Band control metal to insulator transition (BC-MIT)

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

[image]

This is a common diagram seen in describing the metal to insulator transition. I am doing an experiment that involves the Bandwidth control MIT. I think. In other words, I'm changing the temperature and therefore kinetic energy of the charge carriers (t). Can anyone else please offer me a nice explanation as to how this works with varying t? I believe this is what is going on given that I vary the temperature and investigate how this affects current and resistance of magnetite.